# How to compile C code with Neon Intrinsic on 64 bit raspberrypi4 running Linux (using either gcc or clang)?

Tags: gcc, clang, arm64, raspberry-pi4, neon

Q: Which compiler options should be used to compile C code with NEON intrinsic
using #include <arm_neon.h> on raspberry-pi4 (cortex-a72, neon-fp-armv8) running a 64bit Linux OS (Ubuntu)?

On 32bit these options work fine: -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon

However, it doesn't work on aarch64.

(When using default option both CLANG and GCC compile the code with NEON intrinsic without errors, and it is running fine and produce correct result, however looking at the assembly, no NEON code was generated (instructions were replaced with non-vectroized instructions)).

Comment: I can't imagine compilers translating vector instructions to non-vector ones. Unlike `aarch32`, `aarch64` vector instructions don't start with `v`. You should look at the registers instead. (`v`, `d`, and `q` registers vs `w` and `x` registers)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE
Thank you!  - you are correct. I was indeed looking at the instruction.
The source code used the intrinsic "vpmax_f32()", which on 32bit was converted into  "vpmax.f32 d16, d16, d17" which is what I expected, however on the 64bit it was converted into "fmaxp v0.2s, v0.2s, v1.2s", which surprised me - the difference is indeed in the registers.